# Local server get online via VPN

Tags: vpn, local

I'm looking to make my local unix box visible online, but due to the network here, I can't.

Is there a way I can get it to connect to a VPN and then have people access it through that?

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to talk to your local network administrators, most likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do, but that would involve another server:

- Use a vpn to connect the box to another server (linux)
- Install another IP on this server and forward everything to the VPN IP of your box